# Paint Application using mouse-events, Bresenham line, Bresenham midpoint and DDA algo

Tags: java, drawing, mouseevent, line

While I am dragging the mouse pointer to draw the image, the image is getting drawn, but it does not correspond with the mouse pointer. I want to know how I can improve it. I would also like to know how I can improve the overall code. 
[see where the mouse is and drawing is, just after releasing mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kayoO.jpg)

```
    public class Gui2 extends JFrame{       
        private JPanel inputoutput = new JPanel();
        private JPanel container = new JPanel();
        private CartesianPanel mousepanel = new CartesianPanel();
        private JLabel statusbar = new JLabel("default"); // to give status
        private JPanel shape = new JPanel(); //where button is
        private enum DrawingShape {ELLIPSE, RECTANGLE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, POLYGON, LINE; }
        private DrawingShape shapes;
        private String design;
        private int count, count1;
        private String lineAlgo;
        private int X1, X2, Y1, Y2;
        private  Color colour = (Color.BLACK);
        private int a=0, n=0;
        public int[] x_points = new int[10];
        public int[] y_points = new int[10];
        //buttons to set enable, disable
        private JRadioButton thick1 = new JRadioButton("1");
        private JRadioButton thick3 = new JRadioButton("2");
        private JRadioButton thick5 = new JRadioButton("3");
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        private static int scale = 1;
        private double tix,tiy;
        private double radius;
        private double p;

        public Gui2(){ 
// interface implementation goes here
        }

        private class click extends JPanel implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass();
                mousepanel.addMouseListener(handler);
                mousepanel.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
                String command = e.getActionCommand();
                if (command.equals("Color"))
                {
                    colour = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "pick your colour", colour);
                    if (colour == null)
                        colour = (Color.BLACK);

                }
                if (command.equals("Rectangle"))
                {
                    shapes = DrawingShape.RECTANGLE;
                }
                if (command.equals("Circle"))
                {
                    shapes = DrawingShape.CIRCLE;
                }
                if (command.equals("Triangle"))
                {
                    shapes = DrawingShape.TRIANGLE;
                }
                if (command.equals("Ellipse"))
                {
                    shapes = DrawingShape.ELLIPSE;
                }
                if (command.equals("Polygon"))
                {
                    shapes = DrawingShape.POLYGON;
                    String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of edges");
                    n = Integer.parseInt(fn);
                }
                if (command.equals("Line"))
                {
                    shapes = DrawingShape.LINE;
                    thick1.setEnabled(true);
                    thick3.setEnabled(true);
                    thick5.setEnabled(true);
                }
                if(command.equals("Solid"))
                    design = "Solid";
                if(command.equals("Dotted"))
                    design = "Dotted";
                if(command.equals("Dashed"))
                    design = "Dashed";
                if(command.equals("1"))
                    design = "1";
                if(command.equals("2"))
                    design = "2";
                if(command.equals("3"))
                    design = "3";
                if (command.equals("Bresenham Algorithm"))
                {
                    lineAlgo = "Bresenham";
                }
                if (command.equals("DDA"))
                {
                    lineAlgo = "DDA";
                }
            }
        }
        // Other setter methods
        public void setX1(int x) { X1= x; }
        public void setY1(int y) { Y1 = y; }
        public void setX2(int x) { X2 = x; }
        public void setY2(int y) { Y2 = y; }

        // Getter methods
        public Color getColour() { return colour; }
        public int getX1() { return X1; }
        public int getY1() { return Y1; }
        public int getX2() { return X2; }
        public int getY2() { return Y2; }

        private class Handlerclass extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
        { 
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {

                statusbar.setText(String.format("Clicked at %d,%d", e.getX(), e.getY()));
                    if (shapes == shapes.TRIANGLE)
                    {
                        x_points[a] = e.getX();
                        y_points[a] = e.getY();
                        a++;
                        if (a>=3)
                        {
                            System.out.println(x_points);
                            drawShape(x_points,y_points,3,e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3, true);
                            a=0;
                            x_points = new int[10];
                            y_points = new int[10];
                        }
                    }
                    if (shapes==shapes.POLYGON)
                    {
                        x_points[a] = e.getX();
                        y_points[a] = e.getY();
                        a++;
                        if (a>=n)
                        {
                            System.out.println(x_points);
                            drawShape(x_points,y_points,n,e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3, true);
                            a=0;
                            x_points = new int[10];
                            y_points = new int[10];
                        }
                    }
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                statusbar.setText(String.format("Pressed at %d,%d", X1, Y1));
                setX1(e.getX());
                setY1(e.getY());
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                statusbar.setText(String.format("You release the mouse at: %d, %d", e.getX(), e.getY()));
                setX2(e.getX());
                setY2(e.getY());
                drawShape(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3, true);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("You have enter the area");
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("The mouse has left the window");
            }
            //mousemotion
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
            {
                statusbar.setText("You are draggin the mouse to form shape");
            }
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("You moved the mouse");
            }
        }

        private void drawShape(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, boolean fill, boolean paint) 
        {
            // All painting is done on the panel's Graphics object
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g.setColor(getColour());
            if (paint)
                // Shape is to be drawn permanently
                g.setPaintMode();
            else
                g.setXORMode(mousepanel.getBackground());
            int minX = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int minY = Math.min(y1, y2);
            int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
            int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
            switch (shapes) {
                case LINE:
                    if(lineAlgo == "Bresenham")
                    {
                        if ((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2)) {           
                            if(design =="Solid" || design=="1")
                                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y1);
                            if(design =="Dashed")
                            {
                                Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
                                g2d.setStroke(dashed);
                                g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

                                //gets rid of the copy
                                g2d.dispose();
                            }
                            if(design =="Dotted")
                            {
                                    if(count<1)
                                    {
                                        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y1);
                                        count++;
                                        if(count==1)
                                            count1=0;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        count1++;
                                        if(count1==2)
                                            count=0;
                                    }
                             }

                        } else {              
                            int rozdil = dx - dy;

                            int pos_x, pos_y;

                            if (x1 < x2) pos_x = 1; else pos_x = -1;
                            if (y1 < y2) pos_y = 1; else pos_y = -1;

                            while ((x1 != x2) || (y1 != y2)) {  

                                int p = 2 * rozdil;

                                if (p > -dy) {
                                    rozdil = rozdil - dy;
                                    x1 = x1 + pos_x;  
                                }
                                if (p < dx) {
                                    rozdil = rozdil + dx;
                                    y1 = y1 + pos_y; 
                                }
                                if(design =="Solid" || design=="1")
                                    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y1);

                                if(design =="Dashed")
                                {
                                    Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
                                    g2d.setStroke(dashed);
                                    g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

                                    //gets rid of the copy
                                    g2d.dispose();
                                }
                                if(design =="Dotted")
                                {
                                        if(count<1)
                                        {
                                            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y1);
                                            count++;
                                            if(count==1)
                                                count1=0;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            count1++;
                                            if(count1==2)
                                                count=0;
                                        }
                                 }

                            }
                        } 
                    }
                    else if(lineAlgo == "DDA")
                    {
                        if (dy <= dx) 
                        {
                            if ((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2)) {
                                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y1);

                            } else {
                                if (x2 < x1) {
                                    int tmp = x2;
                                    x2 = x1;
                                    x1 = tmp;

                                    tmp = y2;
                                    y2 = y1;
                                    y1 = tmp;
                                }

                                double k = (double)dy/dx; 
                                int new_y;           
                                double y = (double)y1;

                                for (int x = x1 ; x <= x2 ; x++) {
                                    new_y = (int)Math.round(y);
                                    if(design =="Solid" || design=="1")
                                        g.drawLine(x, new_y, x, new_y);

                                    if(design =="Dashed")
                                    {
                                        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
                                        g2d.setStroke(dashed);
                                        g2d.drawLine(x, new_y, x, new_y);

                                        //gets rid of the copy
                                        g2d.dispose();
                                    }
                                    if(design =="Dotted")
                                    {
                                            if(count<1)
                                            {
                                                g.drawLine(x, new_y, x, new_y);
                                                count++;
                                                if(count==1)
                                                    count1=0;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                count1++;
                                                if(count1==2)
                                                    count=0;
                                            }
                                     }
                                    y += k;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {

                                if (y2 < y1) {
                                    int tmp = x2;
                                    x2 = x1;
                                    x1 = tmp;

                                    tmp = y2;
                                    y2 = y1;
                                    y1 = tmp;
                                }

                                double k = (double)dx/dy;
                                int new_x;
                                double x = (double)x1;
                                for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++) {
                                    new_x = (int)Math.round(x);

                                    if(design =="Solid" || design=="1")
                                        g.drawLine(new_x, y, new_x, y);

                                    if(design =="Dashed")
                                    {
                                        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
                                        g2d.setStroke(dashed);
                                        g2d.drawLine(new_x, y, new_x, y);

                                        //gets rid of the copy
                                        g2d.dispose();
                                    }
                                    if(design =="Dotted")
                                    {
                                            if(count<1)
                                            {
                                                g.drawLine(new_x, y, new_x, y);
                                                count++;
                                                if(count==1)
                                                    count1=0;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                count1++;
                                                if(count1==2)
                                                    count=0;
                                            }
                                     }
                                    x += k;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(design==null){
                            g.drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                        }
                        if(design =="Solid" || design=="1")
                            g.drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                        if(design =="Dashed")
                        {
                            Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
                            g2d.setStroke(dashed);
                            g2d.drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                            //gets rid of the copy
                            g2d.dispose();
                        }
                        if(design =="Dotted")
                        {
                                if(count<1)
                                {
                                    g.drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                                    count++;
                                    if(count==1)
                                        count1=0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    count1++;
                                    if(count1==2)
                                        count=0;
                                }
                        }
                        if(design =="2")
                        {
                            Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(3f);
                            g2d.setStroke(stroke);
                            g2d.drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                            g2d.dispose();
                        }
                        if(design =="3")
                        {
                            Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(5f);
                            g2d.setStroke(stroke);
                            g2d.drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                            g2d.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case RECTANGLE:
                    if (fill)
                        g.fillRect(minX, minY, dx, dy);
                    else
                        g.drawRect(minX, minY, dx, dy);
                    break;
                case CIRCLE:  
                    radius=Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1))+((y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
                    //block radius of circle
                    Dimension cal = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                    if ((y1-radius)<35)
                    {
                        radius=y1-35;
                    }
                    if ((x1-radius)<15)
                    {
                        radius=x1-15;
                    }
                    if ((x1+radius)>cal.width)
                    {
                        radius=cal.width-x1;
                    }
                    if ((y1+radius)>cal.height-35)
                    {   
                        radius=cal.height-35-y1;
                    }
                    tix=0;
                    tiy=radius;
                    do  
                    {
                        if(p<0)
                            p=p+(2*tix)+1;
                        else
                        {
                           p=p+(2*tix)+1-(2*tiy);
                           tiy=tiy-1;
                        }

                        tix=tix+1;
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1+tix,y1+tiy,x1+tix,y1+tiy));
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1+tiy,y1+tix,x1+tiy,y1+tix));
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1+tiy,y1-tix,x1+tiy,y1-tix));
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1+tix,y1-tiy,x1+tix,y1-tiy));
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1-tix,y1-tiy,x1-tix,y1-tiy));
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1-tiy,y1-tix,x1-tiy,y1-tix));
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1-tiy,y1+tix,x1-tiy,y1+tix));
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1-tix,y1+tiy,x1-tix,y1+tiy));

                    }while(tix<tiy);

                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                    //g.drawString("Centre("+df.format(((x1-size.width/2.0)/20.0)*scale) +","+ df.format(((size.height/2.0-y1)/20.0)*scale)+")",x1,y1);
                    g.drawString("radius:" +df.format(((radius/20.0)*scale)),(int) x1,(int) y1);
                    break; 
                case ELLIPSE:
                    int xc = x1;
                    int yc = y1;
                    int x = x2;
                    int y = y2; 
                    int sigma;
                    int xr=(int)Math.sqrt(((x-xc)*(x-xc))); //+((y1-Y)*(y1-Y)));
                    int yr=(int)Math.sqrt((y-yc)*(y-yc));
                    int a2 = xr * xr;
                    int b2 = yr * yr;
                    int fa2 = 4 * a2, fb2 = 4 * b2;

                    if ((y-yr)<35)
                    {
                        yr=y-35;
                    }
                    if ((x-xr)<15)

                        xr=x-15;

                    if ((x+xr)>size.width)

                        xr=size.width-x;

                    if ((y+yr)>size.height-35)
                    {   
                        yr=size.height-35-y;
                    }

                    DecimalFormat da = new DecimalFormat("#.##");                   
                    //g.drawString("Centre("+da.format(((xc-size.width/2)/20.0)*scale) +","+ da.format((((size.height/2)-yc)/20.0)*scale)+")", (int)xc, (int)yc);
                        /* first half */
                        for (x = 0, y = yr, sigma = 2*b2+a2*(1-2*yr); b2*x <= a2*y; x++)
                        {
                            g2d.drawLine((int)(xc + x), (int)(yc + y),(int)(xc + x), (int)(yc + y)); 
                            g2d.drawLine ((int)(xc - x),(int)( yc + y),(int)(xc - x),(int)( yc + y));
                            g2d.drawLine ((int)(xc + x), (int)(yc - y),(int)(xc + x), (int)(yc - y));
                            g2d.drawLine ((int)(xc - x), (int)(yc - y),(int)(xc - x), (int)(yc - y));
                            if (sigma >= 0)
                            {
                                sigma += fa2 * (1 - y);
                                y--;
                            }
                            sigma += b2 * ((4 * x) + 6);
                        }

                        /* second half */
                        for (x = xr, y = 0, sigma = 2*a2+b2*(1-2*xr); a2*y <= b2*x; y++)
                        {
                            g2d.drawLine((int)(xc + x), (int)(yc + y),(int)(xc + x), (int)(yc + y)); 
                            g2d.drawLine ((int)(xc - x), (int)(yc + y),(int)(xc - x), (int)(yc + y));
                            g2d.drawLine ((int)(xc + x), (int)(yc - y),(int)(xc + x), (int)(yc - y));
                            g2d.drawLine ((int)(xc - x), (int)(yc - y),(int)(xc - x), (int)(yc - y));
                            if (sigma >= 0)
                            {
                                sigma += fb2 * (1 - x);
                                x--;
                            }
                            sigma += a2 * ((4 * y) + 6);
                        }

                    break;
            }
        }

        private void drawShape(int[] x, int[] y, int N, boolean fill, boolean paint)
        {
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            g.setColor(getColour());
            if (paint)
                g.setPaintMode();
            else
                g.setXORMode(mousepanel.getBackground());
            switch (shapes) {
                case TRIANGLE:
                    if (fill)
                        g.fillPolygon(x, y, N);
                    else
                        g.drawPolygon(x, y, N);
                    break;
                case POLYGON:
                    if (fill)
                        g.fillPolygon(x, y, N);
                    else
                        g.drawPolygon(x, y, N);
                    break;
            }
        }

        class CartesianPanel extends JPanel {
   //implementation of scalable Cartesian plane
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to improve the example so more people will be willing to help http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve